# Trying to watch for changes in .evtx

Tags: python, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am trying to see changes in the file Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Operational.evtx but the script does not recognize them
My purpose is to be able to see when the file changes so that I can always extract the last line.
I am using watchdog

```
import watchdog.events
import watchdog.observers
import time
import subprocess
last_trigger_time = time.time()
class Handler(watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        # Set the patterns for PatternMatchingEventHandler
        watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, patterns=['Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Operational.evtx'],
                                                             ignore_directories=True, case_sensitive=False)
    def on_modified(self, event):
        global last_trigger_time
        current_time = time.time()
        if event.src_path.find('~') == -1 and (current_time - last_trigger_time) > 1:
            last_trigger_time = current_time
            print('Archivo Modificado')
            #subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", "Get-WinEvent -Path Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Operational.evtx -MaxEvents 1 | Export-Csv -Path Prueba.csv"], capture_output=True)
            #print('CSV Generado')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    src_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs"
    event_handler = Handler()
    observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=src_path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```